# Gridview controls in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have one `GridView`  with the column names `itemname`, `category` and `date`. Additionally, I have `add`, `update`, `edit`, `cancel` and `delete` buttons. If I click the `delete` button, the `selectedrow` of `Gridview` changes to another color (disabled).

Again I go to the same page that `selectedrow` display disable mode and other rows displays normal.

Comment: Your question n title still not clear, describe more so its helps reader to give proper answer

Answer (score 1):

yes i have done this in my project

i am giving you some apporch to how you can do that . If you are deleting any row data you must have store somevalue like when i delete any data of the row i set its value of 7 then on grid rowcommand i find if that status is 7 then i change the color of that row ..
And how you will do that this is the code .

you put one label on the `gridview` where you put the status of the record like deleted

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
      <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("StatusID") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField> 




protected void GridView1_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
      Label myLabel = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblStatus");
      string value = myLabel.Text;

      if (value == "7")

         {
           e.Row.BackColor = Color.Red;
         }
   }
```